# Spring mass system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, velocity, spring

While solving some spring block questions one doubt came in my mind ..is it possible to calculate maximum velocity of a point between two springs of different force constant attached to a block of some mass and stretched to a finite distance slowly? enter image description here
[image]

Lets say if in this diagram i have to find the velocity of A...

Will it be the same as maximum velocity of the body ..if we find effective spring constant and apply energy conservation to find maximum velocity of the body?

Comment: Welcome to the stack exchange. If this is a homework problem, please add that tag. On homework problems we like to have the student put at least some effort into solving the problem. Also be clear, specific on what the question is. The answer to is it possible? - yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can assume $x_1$ and $x_2$ as the extension from both the side
Then $x_1+x_2=\text{length stretched}$

Since the force on the point will be zero as it is mass less we can equate the force on it
$$k_1x_1=k_2x_2 $$

Now putting $x_1$ in the first equation and get the value of $x_2$.

And since the system is performing SHM 
Maximum velocity will be $A\omega$ where 
A is amplitude and $\omega =\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$, $k$ will be the effective spring constant.

Since in this case it is in series effective spring constant will be $$\frac{k_1\times k_2}{k_1+k_2}$$

Therefore maximum velocity will be 
$$x_1\times \sqrt{k/m}$$